# Describe table from Athena data source in DataGrip fails

Tags: mysql, aws, redshift, datagrip

Whenever I attempt to Describe an AWS Athena table in DataGrip it fails. The error states that is is a permissions error but I am fairly certain it is not. In fact, I can describe tables using SQLWorkbench/j and the Athena console without issue. It is only a problem in DataGrip.

The query I am running is simply DESCRIBE schemaName.TableName;

[image: Error pictured here]

Is this normal or an issue or something I am doing incorrectly in DG.

Comment: It could be limitation of JDBC driver. Could you try to contact AWS support about that question?

Comment: I've seen this in datagrip as well. Also seen verry similar errors for other actions. It looked to be related to the JDBC driver, you can try  using the one provided by amazon as the datagrip provided driver is usually a few versions behind. I've found this can help but not always a fix. In general I've found if I can't reproduce in the AWS Athena Query Console it comes back to something weird with the JDBC.